# Vector Graphic Pin to Edge Constraints

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

Is it possible to pin an object to an edge (of an object, path, or document) such that when the document is resized, the object will change its x,y coordinates such that it maintains the same distance to the edge. I generally use Illustrator for vector graphics, but a solution in Inkscape or a similar environment is good too.

All answers appreciated and I always accept one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond using effects, such as offset path, **no** it is not possible. The effect don't sound like they are what you are seeking.